# Pypetteer and Asyncio: scrape page, perform action, scrape the new page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio

I am trying to write a web scraping tool for a certain URL by using pypetteer and asyncio (Mind that I am using both libraries for the first time, so I might have skipped something really trivial). I tried using just requests, but the website changes its tables purely with JavaScript, without any affect on the URL.

My goal is to scrape the first page, emulate a click on the next page button, then scrape the next page, and so on and so forth. Here is the code I have so far

```
from math import ceil
import numpy as np
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import pickle as pkl
from pyppeteer import launch
from tqdm import trange

URL = "https://studiegids.uva.nl/xmlpages/page/2020-2021-en/search-course"

async def get_page(browser, url, selector):
    """Return a page after waiting for the given selector"""
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)
    await page.waitForSelector(selector)
    return page


async def get_table(browser, page_count):
    """Return the table from the given page number as a pandas dataframe"""
    page = await get_page(browser, URL, "table")
    tables = list()
    for _ in trange(page_count):
        current_html = await page.querySelectorEval(
                "table", "(element) => element.outerHTML")
        current_tables = pd.read_html(current_html)
        tables.append(current_tables)
        linkHandlers = await page.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'next')]")
        await linkHandlers[-1].click()
    # await page.screenshot({'path': 'a.png', 'fullPage': True})
    return tables


async def get_results():
    browser = await launch(args=["--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"])
    page_num = 10  # For testing
    return await get_table(browser, page_num)


page_tables = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_results())
```

What I expected this to do was to give me the tables in the first 10 pages. However, what I get is 10 copies of the table on the initial page. When I follow the same steps in the for loop below manually (without the loop),

```
for _ in trange(page_count):
    current_html = await page.querySelectorEval(
            "table", "(element) => element.outerHTML")
    current_tables = pd.read_html(current_html)
    tables.append(current_tables)
    linkHandlers = await page.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'next')]")
    await linkHandlers[-1].click()
```

I am able to get different pages, which I asserted with screenshots. Can anyone see where it is going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Added the URL to the code.

Edit2:

The working code is as follows (this works in an interactive ipython session, executed line by line):

```
browser = await launch(args=["--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"])
page = await get_page(browser, URL, "table") # a function I created, can be seen above

current_html1 = await page.querySelectorEval("table","(element) => element.outerHTML")
current_tables1 = pd.read_html(current_html)

linkHandlers = await page.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'next')]")
await linkHandlers[-1].click()

current_html2 = await page.querySelectorEval("table","(element) => element.outerHTML")
current_tables2 = pd.read_html(current_html)

linkHandlers = await page.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'next')]")
await linkHandlers[-1].click()

current_html3 = await page.querySelectorEval("table","(element) => element.outerHTML")
current_tables3 = pd.read_html(current_html)
```

The resultant list of tables are different, each giving me a different page's tables.

Comment: Can you please show the code that does it manually, i.e. without a loop? You can keep it to two or three "iterations" for brevity.

Comment: @user4815162342 of course, let me make another edit

Comment: After the second edit there is still some confusion left. It would be nice if you could edit the _script_ to include the unrolled code, to eliminate the possibility of ipython interactive code somehow affecting execution (e.g. by providing more time for some coroutine to run in the background while you are typing in the next line). The other confusing thing is that you store the result of `querySelectorEqual` to variables named `current_html1`, `current_html2`, and `current_html3`, but always pass `current_html` to `pd.read_html()`. Is that intentional?